# siunitx fonts in math and text mode always identical

Tags: fontspec, siunitx, unicode-math

I am stuck with configuring siunitx to my liking.

Using LuaLaTex and fontspec I want siunitx to print numbers and units in normal text font when in text. When in math mode I want it to print numbers in serif math font and units in sans serif text font. 
No matter what I change, it always affects both typesettings, inside and outside of math mode.

Her is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, german]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}           
    \setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Tex Gyre Heros}[Scale=0.91]            
    \setsansfont{Tex Gyre Heros}[Scale=0.93, LetterSpace=0, WordSpace=0.96]
    \setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}[Scale=0.95]
\usepackage{microtype}  



\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{siunitx}
            \sisetup{%detect-all,
                    math-rm=\mathsf,
                    text-rm=\sffamily,
                    binary-units=true, %use binary units
                    per-mode=fraction, %\per inserts fraction
                    output-decimal-marker={,} %comma as decimal sperator
                    }

\begin{document}

In text I want siunitx to print sans serif text font: 1000kV, \SI{1000}{\kilo\volt}

In math mode I want it to print numbers in serif math font: $1000kV, \SI{1000}{\kilo\volt}$

\end{document}
```

Which gives this output:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You mention what numbers should look like if `\SI` is encountered in math mode. What about the units, though: should they use sans serif or serif?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. In math mode I want numbers serif and units sans serif

Comment: Speaking for myself, I find that using serif numbers together with sans-serif units looks weird.

Comment: Thanks for this question: you've contributed to v3 of `siunitx` :) (See https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/commit/5e7198838a18e6bce8a6bbae3f21f7b573e85b58, which is for exactly this case.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses (a) sans-serif glyphs for both numbers and units if `\SI` is encountered in text mode and (b) serif glyphs for both numbers and units if `\SI` is encountered in math mode. This may be achieved by setting the `siunitx` options `math-rm=\symup` and `detect-all`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, german]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Tex Gyre Heros}[Scale=0.91]
\usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
    \setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{math-rm=\symup,detect-all}

\begin{document}

Text mode: 1000\,kV, \SI{1000}{\kilo\volt} --- sans serif text font

Math mode: $1000\,\symup{kV}$, $\SI{1000}{\kilo\volt}$ --- serif math font

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like how this looks. Thank you. Can you explain how you came up with the `math-rm=\symup` option?

Comment: @namron - The basic LaTeX font-selection commands are `\mathrm`, `\textrm`, etc. To use `\mathcal`, `\mathscr`, `\mathfrak`, is generally necessary to load additional packages (e.g., `amssymb`). The `unicode-math` package offers many new font-selection commands; they generally begin with the "prefix" `\sym`: `\symup`, `\symit`, `\symbf`, `\symbfit`, `\symscr`, `\symcal`, etc. If one uses the `unicode-math` package, one might as well make use of its commands, right? :-)

Comment: @namron - Another thing to keep in mind is that `\mathrm`, `mathit`, etc take letter glyphs from the *text* font. This is likely due to old technical limitations of math fonts. With unicode-based math font families, it's in principle no longer necessary to do so. However, the old settings still apply to the actions of `\mathrm`, `\mathit`, etc, presumably for the worthy objective of maintaining backward compatibily. If backward compatibility and, relatedly, the ability to recompile 25-year-old documents aren't a priority, one might as well use `\symup`, `\symit`, etc., right?

Comment: @Mico It's a bit more complicated than that: the semantic meaning may be different ... one for TUG2018 I hope

Comment: @JosephWright - Thanks for this heads-up. I certainly look forward to attending your talk (talks, actually!) in Rio!

Comment: Is there any way to use the same font for both the text and the math mode?

Comment: @JosephWright I would be grateful if you could take a look at [my relevant question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/562979/2288).