# siunitx uses weird font in math mode

Tags: math-mode, siunitx

When changing the text font to opensans, then siunitx decides to use a third sans serif font in math mode.

Is this still the case with the current texlive release?

If so, how can I fix this behavior?

The solution provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438342/63717) didn't help.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[default]{opensans}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{50mm}
    Text mode:                \\
    expecting: 5.1\,N         \\
    getting:  \SI{5.1}{N}
\end{minipage}


\begin{minipage}[t]{50mm}
    Math mode:                \\
    expecting: $ a = 5.1\,\mathrm{N} $ \\
    getting:   $ a = \SI{5.1}{N} $  
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
As daleif pointed out in his/her comment below, the behavior is different when using `lato` instead of `opensans`. With the former, the output in math mode is correct, and now output in text mode fails.

**Update, Version 2020/02/25:**
The output has changed. Now I get
[image]

**Update, Version v3.0.38, last revised 2022-01-04:**
The output now matches my expectations without any modification of the LaTeX code required:
[image: output_v3.0.38]
The same output is obtained when using `mode=match` instead of `detect-all` as pointed out by Joseph Wright in his answer.

Comment: It might be `opensans` that does something non standard. With `lato` I get exacly as expected (all N's except the first in a serif font)

Comment: @daleif I disagree; the output you are getting is erroneous too. 
With `detect-all` the two outputs on the left should be identical (text font) and the two on the right should be identical (math font).

Comment: Nope, your mistaken. The manual reads "By default, all text is typeset in the current upright math font. This can be changed
by setting the appropriate options: \sisetup{detect-all} will use the current font for typesetting." I'm using detect-all in the MWE, so I would expect both outputs on the left not to be in math font.

Comment: My bad, I think I confused table 12 and 13

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Version 3 answer

With version 3 of `siunitx`, the only thing you need to set here is `mode = match` so you select text or math mode output. Other than that, you will get the same font as your 'reference' input.

### Version 2 answer

The detection in `siunitx` picks up that `opensans` is sanserif, so uses `\mathsf` not `\mathrm`/`\mathnormal` for the standard math mode typesetting. That is with your set up Computer Modern. You can reset that by adjusting how `math-sf` is interpretted by giving `\sisetup{math-sf = \mathrm}`.

Comment: fantastic, this fixes it, makes me wonder though if there is not a bug in the implementation of siunitx: The manual reads "\sisetup{detect-all} will use the current font for typesetting." So I would expect the current math font to be used and not the sans-serif math font.

Comment: @Bastian Ah well that's one of those edge cases. In the current set up, I do effectively `\mbox{\ensuremath{...}}` for the content, so I have to reset the math mode font. That means knowing what it is, and getting it right. I really do need to finish v3, which uses an alternative method which is less invasive.

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer! Aha, `detect-all` and `mode=match` seem to do the same thing. I think I will be able to remember `mode=match` better, so that's what I'll go with then.