# fonts / siunitx: Understanding how "detect-all" and "detect-inline-family=math" work

Tags: fonts, fontspec, siunitx, unicode-math

For the following, I need to

1. understand why neither `detect-all` nor `detect-inline-family=math` doesn't make `\num` print the same font as the surrounding inline math, and the only way to do so is through `math-rm = \symup` as suggested by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438342/2288).
2. understand why I need to load the option `math-rm = \symup` in order to make `\num` copy the document default math font.
3. know if it is possible to make the default math font-weight as light as the surrounding normal text since it looks a bit bolder for my eyes.

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=ISO]{Cambria Math}

\usepackage[
detect-all,
detect-inline-family=math
]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \centering
    text: 123 \num{123}\\
    inline math: $123~\num{123}$\\
    display math: \[123~\num{123}\]
    
    \verb|\sisetup{math-rm = \symup}|
    \sisetup{math-rm = \symup} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438342/2288
    
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    text: 123 \num{123}\\
    inline math: $123~\num{123}$\\
    display math: \[123~\num{123}\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\mathrm` (and `\mathbf` etc) uses in the default setup glyphs from the surrounding text font, `\symrm` (and `\symbf`? etc) uses glyphs from the math font:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmathfont[math-style=ISO]{Cambria Math}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
$\mathrm{mathrm}\quad\symrm{symrm}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

By default `\num` uses one of the `\mathXXX` fonts, and by default this `\mathXXX` fonts uses text fonts, and so `\num` uses a text font even in math. With `math-rm = \symup` you can force it to use the math font.

`detect-inline-family=math` doesn't mean that `\num` will use a math font, it means that `\num` will react if it is inside a math command. Try for example

```
  $123~\num{456}~\mathsf{\num{789}}$
```

[image]

> 3. know if it is possible to make the default math font-weight as light as the surrounding

Well Cambria Math is a bit bolder. Why don't you use the default (latin modern math) which would fit better?

Comment: I have a basic question if you don't mind; what is the difference in meaning between `math-rm = \symup` and `math-rm = \symrm`? Out of curiosity, I replaced the former with the latter in your code, and the result didn't change. So, Would you please explain the meaning of each one?

Comment: Interestingly, [this document](https://pastebin.com/SS0y4Ce2) doesn't need `math-rm=\symup` to make `\num` copy the surrounding font attributes when using the same family for both text and math `:)`. Apparently, I created an issue out accidentally out of nothing.